# Constraining a fixed attribute such that it may only appear on one element

Tags: xsd

I am taking my first steps in XML-schema land, using XSD, and I'm trying to figure out how to add a constraint such that an attribute (defined with a fixed value) may only be present on one element in an unbounded set of elements.

Here's an example

```
<Object>
    <Element>Value1</Element>
    <Element>Value2</Element>
    <Element Default="true">Value3</Element>
    <Element>Value4</Element>
    <Element>Value5</Element>
</Object>
```

I'd like to constrain the `Default` attribute such that it cannot appear on more than one `Element`.

Here's the XSD schema for the above:

```
<xs:element name="Object">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="Element" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="Default" fixed="true"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I've tried messing with `xs:unique`, `xs:selector` and `xs:field`, but reached no meaningful results, not sure if that's the correct approach.

Thanks!

Comment: This question earned me the Tumbleweed badge, yay :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried my best to design one xsd for you. The possible way to achieve the requirement is to define element `element` more than ones, but this is not allowed under XSD causing a popular error **"trying to make XSD Ambiguous"**

So your requirement is certainly impossible to achieve as is.

I would like to suggest to define different Element names.

example :: define `DefElement` with attribute and unbounded `Element`s without attribute. It would work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort :) I have accepted the answer even though it provides an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but look at here : [XSD Specifying an attribute that can be used only once in the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065095/xsd-specifying-an-attribute-that-can-be-used-only-once-in-the-xml/22065834#22065834)

There is a close solution (but not complete) : define the attribute as one-value boolean (only true), optional, no default value and unique.

(+) 
- Do check that there is only one Default="true"
- Do check that there is only one Default attribute defined

(-)
- Do not check that there is at least one Default attribute defined