# XSD Specifying an attribute that can be used only once in the XML

Tags: xml, xsd

Having a complexType with several attributes:

```
<xs:complexType name="baseType" mixed="true">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="leader" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="person" type="baseType"/>
```

How can I restrict the `leader` attribute to be used only once in the XML file? so the following will not validate (cannot be two leaders)

```
<person name="Charlie"/>
<person name="Megan" leader="true"/>
<person name="Moe"/>
<person name="Jonathan" leader="true"/>
<person name="Claire"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce "at most once" if you give the `leader` attribute a type that has only one possible value (e.g. a type that derives by restriction from `boolean` and allows only true), then add a `unique` constraint at the level of the *parent* element that contains the person elements, stating that person elements must have unique values of their `leader` attribute. Since unique constraints only apply to elements where the field is actually present, this will ensure that no more than one person has a `leader` attribute, and when that attribute is present it must be true.

I don't think there's a way to enforce "at least one" in XML Schema 1.0, you could do it with an assertion if you can use 1.1.

Comment: If I use restriction based on pattern would it be the right way to restrict a boolean to "true"?

Comment: @ilomambo personally I'd use an enumeration to make it perfectly clear that I want to allow just one specific value.

Comment: Enumeration did not work for me, the Eclipse validator threw an error, I also tried using min, max values. The only way it worked was with pattern.

Comment: You could enforce at least one by using key instead of unique; key must be present, unique doesn't.

Comment: @PetruGardea I thought a key meant the field has to be present on _every_ element matched by the selector?

Comment: Yes, you're right about it, I just confused the scenario. Just for the sake of doing it... There's one way though to enforce at least once... You could create an element inside the person collection (say `<constraints>`), with a mandatory attribute matching the person's attribute leader's type (say @leader-on-file); keyref that attribute with the unique constraint... and it works.